# Slide-bar how to change a value vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, uislider

Im newbe in vue.js. I tried to create a slide-bar with min and max value.

I found some and installed vue range slider. I implemented it and it has worked.

Problem is, when I tried to change a value on slider. I get some value from api request, which are an array: `[400, 600, 800, 1000, 1200, 1400, 1600, 1800, 2000, 2500, 3000,]`. But my max in slide have to be a number, not an array.

I tried to find a info in documentation, how to change this max value, but find nothing :/ 
My slide bar looks like this https://frncsdrk.github.io/vue-slide-bar-demo-page/.

I would like to change the values ​​to those given in the array.

```
HTML
         .box_slider 
                  VueSlideBar(v-model="value"
                  :min="0"
                  :max="sliderAmount" //this is my value
                  :processStyle="slider.processStyle"
                  :lineHeight="slider.lineHeight"
                  :tooltipStyles="{ backgroundColor: 'red', borderColor: 
                  'red' }"
                  class="demo-demo" id="slider-1")

 VUE.JS
      <script>
      import co from "@/util/co.js";
      import VueSlideBar from "vue-slide-bar";
       var sliderAmount;
     export default {
       name: "Repaid",
     components: {
      VueSlideBar
         },
        data() {
         return {
       slider: {
         lineHeight: 10
            },
            sliderAmount: undefined
         };
          },
        methods: {},
      mounted() {
          co.getLoanPriceList().then(data => {
          let dataLoan = data.data;
            console.log(dataLoan);
        this.sliderAmount = dataLoan.amounts;
         return this.sliderAmount;
          });
         },
         computed: {
           sliderAmountMap() {
          const sliderAmountValue = this.sliderAmount;
                 return sliderAmountValue; //this is my value
         console.log(sliderAmountValue);
           }
       }
        };
         </script>
```

Maybe somebody did this kind of slider and can help me to start working with.

**EDIT**

Thanks guys for your time and for suggestion. The solution is to add `slider.data` to component `VueSlideBar`, and create var data with array in data.

HTML

```
     .box_slider {{sliderAmountMap}}
                  VueSlideBar(v-model="value"
                  :min="0"
                  :data="slider.data"
                  :max="sliderAmount"
                  :processStyle="slider.processStyle"
                  :lineHeight="slider.lineHeight"
                  :tooltipStyles="{ backgroundColor: 'red', borderColor: 
                   'red' }"
                  class="demo-demo" id="slider-1")
```

VUE.JS

```
 export default {
   name: "Repaid",
    components: {
     VueSlideBar
   },
     data() {
      return {
       slider: {
       lineHeight: 10,
       data: [400, 600, 800, 1000, 1200, 1400, 1600, 1800, 2000, 2500, 
       3000]
       },
       sliderAmount: undefined
      };
     },
```

Answer (score 1):

You loop  through that array and assign each value to the max props of the slider :

```
     .box_slider (v-for="(item,index) in sliderAmount" v-bind:key="index")
              VueSlideBar(v-model="value"
              :min="0"
              :max="item" //set the value here
              :processStyle="slider.processStyle"
              :lineHeight="slider.lineHeight"
              :tooltipStyles="{ backgroundColor: 'red', borderColor: 
              'red' }"
              class="demo-demo" id="slider-1")
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer but I need them all. During moving a slider I want them to show. Not all,  but one value in one slide.

Comment: you want to create many sliders according to the number of values in that array?

Comment: This is a one slide bar, so when you move the button from left to right, the value should change and show you - only one value from array.  Like this https://frncsdrk.github.io/vue-slide-bar-demo-page/ But I would like to change the values ​​to those given in the array.

Comment: And what's the problem passing your array to `slider.data` like in the second slider on your example page?

Comment: @ElijahEllanski thank you! I'm fool. I was so focused on the first example that I didn't pay attention to other solutions. I wast triang to use slider.value but didn't work. I spent so much time for looking a correctly solution. You made my day! Thanx again!